# how to inspect redirection to non http href using selenium

Tags: java, javascript, android, selenium, browser

I use selenium web-drive to test a web page that is usually shown in my android app (`Android web-view`).

I want to click on a button and check where will be the redirection.

The problem is that

1) sometimes the `href` is static and sometimes the click just triggers an `onClick()` js method that does redirection to another page.

2) Another issue is that the redirection is sometimes an android intent.

in the format: `waze:\\`

[image]

I tried to click on the button and check the `newUrl`, but my browser isn't directing to any other page (in my case it was a static `waze://`)

What do you suggest?

Comment: Is `waze://` a link that can be opened by just a browser alone?

Comment: i cannot know, because putting in the address line gives google result.

Comment: it meant more for android, which triggers an application out of the browser

Comment: I do not think you can do this with the regular WebDriver, this would need to be done with Selenidroid, but if Selenidroid has opened another application you will have no visibility of that.

Comment: @TidusJar `a link that can be opened by just a browser alone` firefox does. chrome doesn't.